Cannot figure out why DTLS handshake does not complete
I am writing a small WebRTC client as a hobby project , right now I am stuck in DTLS implementation and cannot figure out what is going wrong with the DTLS handshake.
I am trying to make a p2p WebRTC connection from My WebRTC implementation and Gstreamer Implementation
I send the client hello as a DTLS client to gstreamer client it responds with server hello certificate key ..... Then I respond with the FLIGHT 4 messages as displayed in below diagram but I do not get a response back for flight 5 from Gstreamer.

(i have attached wireshark pcap and Gstreamer logs )
There Might be some thing wrong with flight 4 that I am sending but I cannot figure out the problem , I have verified all the messages are correct by manually calculating every thing from premaster secret ,master secret , RSA AES ....
I have implemented TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
premaster secret : FEFD9E38B76CF5780B6C58CBB55309C1C08EE1B5DF7D4507159115A8D459C35936FEEC2344698CF4A7F0689714C0BA19 
client random : 39623565396565382d333032332d343865642d383064392d6432346165616538
server random : a9dbe285e2ef980972812e45c86f6aaff1d486212bbb2d93744d2bae14813ae3
SENDING encrypted PREMSATER KEY TO SERVER : 
non-encrypted padded premaster key
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
server public key modulus and exponent 
modulus:
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
exponent : 010001
encrypted premaster key : 
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
I have encrypted the above message with my server's certificate modulus and exponent and send it in key exchange message
DERIVING MASTER SECRET FROM PREMASTER SECRET:
prf result for master secret
991FE0D757F2E3422CB36B287974B8F1CFEA6EA464674D8CCCCA9111AF817BA0934F07F7F376B5ED1F507F7575A7CA03
key expansion for deriving keying material
b2693e4352ac4a9669d92b4ba2a3153a9556b3ff82a347a85713bb4864e8d3cfbed57e8c60f6965cfc10b7c85a88934fa83fe883ee02f1a4fd6392045b87d38775c5e059f75613fefa3208b78d0b61f0245fcc6e10d68c56ab661da1641d132cb0a71ce0fd074cf6149826dbdd70bfc8d6139fccbdbe3182ad80bba13254339d
derived keys:
AES CLIENT key : 88 04 d7 e0 41 c1 5a b4 3a f7 7f 40 d9 fd 0d 13
AES CLIENT IV :  3a f3 3d 4c 30 57 14 6a 22 50 c7 56 97 c3 75 f7
I am then using the above keys to encrypt the finish message with aes cbc and send it.
I can confirm that the certificate verify message is correct because when I send wrong data in certificate verify message then gstreamer responds with bad signature .
non-encrypted Finish message with padding
14 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c ad f8 6f 17 16 a9 3f df 10 b9 c1 9b ca d1 f7 d2 21 58 97 26 72 08 15 bb d8 f0 61 81 49 4e 79 69 03 03 03 03
encrypted finish message
(first 16 bytes are client IV in the message)
3af33d4c3057146a2250c75697c375f710d8335f318be6ee18f3d49be4300e77bbb4aab65eb9caa35e983bad7101bf16920f46cb7822bc67b1801dbf0e0a1ea7
I have verified the encrypted message is correctly encrypted using AES CBC by using this online tool to decrypt and verify that it gets me the original message.
(first 16 bytes is IV so skip them when decrypting )

Gstreamer Logs
Wireshark pcap
UPDATE : I was able to decrypt the DTLS packets using master secret Wireshark 
Wireshark Pcap file 
Wireshark decryption log file 
wireshark decryption premaster secret file 
while inspecting the log file I can see that the expanded keys in wireshark are same as mine and finish message is decrypted correctly and mac is verified correctly and also I know that Gstreamer will return bad signature error when wrong sign is sent but right now I do not get such an error in the log  that means that Client Verify is correct as well , then that leaves my suspicion to only Client key exchange message.

I would guess the encrypted FINISH message isn't right, but I can't tell anything from the Gstreamer logs.

Thank you very much @PresidentJamesK.Polk for taking the time to help me , I have updated the question by adding the details about how I am verifying manually that the encrypted message is correctly encrypted.

You might be doing everything correctly, that I haven't checked, but whether you are or aren't, you still need to know why your peer seems unable to get past the encrypted FINISH message. The logs from that side look more API calls than a real log, but it's very hard to read, so maybe I missed something. I took the liberty of changing one of the tags to maybe get some of the SSL experts to take a look.

That’s quite the undertaking! Have you considered comparing your packet sequences with a complete implementation e.g. in a browser?

@nneonneo Yes I have verified that the sequence number in  dtls header and handshake messages are same as the browser implementation

You know already how to use wireshark. But you don't provide your capture. From your analysis so far "bad signature", I would guess, that the "Certificate Verify" is invalid (doesn't match the client's Certificate).

@AchimKraus Thank you for your response , Sorry for the confusion with my bad English , what I meant was I know that gstreamer gives a bad sign error when wrong sign is sent but I don't get such an error so that is why I think the Certificate Verify message is correct. I have also updated the pcap file in the question. Thank  you.

@nneonneo was correct The main problem was the sequence number  of the "Finished" message in my implementation. Initially, I was comparing my packet sequence numbers against a packet capture that I downloaded from the internet. In that packet capture, the "Change Cipher Spec" message was counted as an increment in the sequence number.
I applied the same logic in my implementation, incrementing the sequence number for the "Change Cipher Spec" message. However, this approach led to the problem I was facing. After some investigation, I realized that the "Change Cipher Spec" message should not trigger a sequence number increment.
When I adjusted my code to not increment the sequence number when sending the "Change Cipher Spec" message, the issue was resolved.

Your capture shows, that the server send messages with a maximum size of 300 bytes. Your client use up to 831 bytes. The server resend after 1s its Server_Hello with sequence number 7.
I would guess, the server has issues with the large messages. e.g. if the server receives the client's Certificate and the Certificate Verify but detects an error, the server would not resend the Server_Hello but an Alert.
So, I would recommend to check the maximum message size and try to reduce that on the client side.

Thanks  you for your recommendations , let me try this and get back to you.

Hi @Achim Kraus , I tried to make the DTLS packet smaller by fragmenting them but that does not seems to solve the problem , the server still does not reply with the flight 5 messages. here is the new dtls packet capture and secret file to decode the packet.

in the above packet capture the max packet size is around 330 bytes , but I have also checked by setting max packet size below 300 and that also does not change anything

Sorry, I'm no WebRTC expert. It was just a guess, that the server has issues with the large messages, though it resend the Server_Hello.
